# Error in Royden? Topological Groups.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, topological-groups, topological-vector-spaces

Theorem: suppose $G$ is a topological group, $E$ a Banach Space, and $\pi$ a representation of $G$ on $E$. Suppose that for all $x\in E$ the map $g\to \pi(g)x$ is continuous: $G\to E$ when $E$ has the norm topology. Finally, suppose that $K^*$ is a weak-$*$ compact subset of $E^*$ that is invariant under $\pi^*.$ Then, there is a functional $\psi\in K^*$ that is fixed under $\pi.$

The proof proceeds as follows: If $\mathcal F$ is the collection of convex, weak-$^*$ closed subsets of $K^*$ invariant under $\pi^*,$ Zorn's Lemma gives us a member of $\mathcal F,$ which we also call $K^*$ for convenience,  minimal with this property. The idea then is to show that $K^*$ is a singleton. If not, there is an $x_0\in E,\ \psi_1,\ \psi_2\in K^*$ such that $\psi_1(x_0)\neq \psi_2(x_0).$ Now define $p(\psi)=\sup_{g\in G}|\psi(\pi(g))x_0)|$

$K^*$ is closed, hence compact, and an application of Banach-Steinhaus shows it is norm bounded. Using this fact, one then shows that $p$ is continuous with respect to the weak$^*$ topology so the sets $B(\eta.r)=\left \{ \psi\in K^{*}:p(\psi-\eta)<r \right \}$ are open and convex (since $p$ is positive and subadditive).

Now define $d=\sup\left \{ p(\phi-\psi):\phi,\psi\in K^* \right \}.\ d>0$ because $p(\psi_1-\psi_2)>0).$

There are $\left \{ \psi_k \right \}^{n}_{k=1}$ such that $\left \{ B_k(\psi_k,d/2) \right \}^{n}_{k=1}$ is a finite cover of $K^*$ and the fact that $K^*$ is convex implies that $\psi^{*}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\psi_k\in K^*.$

Now let $\psi\in K^*.$ Then, $\psi \in B_k(\psi_k,d/2)$ for some $1\le k\le n$ so wlog $k=1$ and then $p(\psi-\psi^*)\le \frac{d}{2}+\frac{1}{n}p((\psi_1-\psi_2)+(\psi_1-\psi_3)+\cdots +(\psi_1-\psi_n))\le\frac{d}{2}+\frac{(n-1)d}{n}=d'$

and it is here that Royden claims that $d'<d$, which is clearly not true.

The rest of the proof, which may be found [here in chapter 22](https://www.ece.umd.edu/class/enee620.F2017/RoydenFitzpatrick.pdf), is clear but relies heavily on what appears to be this false claim, which I have not been able to patch up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typo - it should read $d'=\frac1n((n-1)d+\frac d2) $, which is indeed less than $d$.

Comment: But when I do the calculation, I get the what the typo asserts: $p(\psi-\psi^*)\le p(\psi -\psi_1)+p(\psi_1- \psi^*)\le \frac{d}{2}+\frac{1}{n}p((\psi_1-\psi_2)+(\psi_1-\psi_3)+\cdots +(\psi_1-\psi_n))\le\frac{d}{2}+\frac{(n-1)d}{n}$

Comment: Instead you should write $\psi-\psi^*=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n(\psi-\psi_i)$. Apply $p$ and use positive homogeneity and subadditivity. One summand is bounded by $\frac d2$, the others are all bounded by $d$, and the whole thing is multiplied by $\frac1n$.